# Python package has been already installed but gets No module error while importing

Tags: python, package, file-format

I installed the `fastatocsv` successfully after running the following command on Colab:

```
!pip install fastatocsv
```

But when I want to import the module, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastatocsv'
```

Does someone know anything about what could possibly be happening here?

Comment: Have you tried reinstall or specify the latest version when installing?

Comment: Try running `pip show fastalocsv` or `pip list`, and check if it is even installed correctly. If it does show, check if your python environment is correct.

Comment: `pip freeze` to check current installed packages

Comment: after installing, Did you restart your kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the README-EXAMPLE was never updated

try

```
    import fasta2csv
```

Comment: there is no package named  fasta2csv

Comment: I tried it you have to "pip install fastatocsv" and then import it with "import fasta2csv"

Comment: tnx. now I can import but the problem is when I try to use the package ```fasta2csv.converter.convert("data/9606.protein.sequences.v11.5.fa","STRINGsequence.csv")
``` I get this error AttributeError: module 'fasta2csv' has no attribute 'converter'

Comment: try "import fasta2csv.converter"

Comment: tnx, It solved my problem! But why it didn't work when we import fasta2csv only? without converter?!

Comment: Because converter seems to be an second module inside the fasta2csv module which is not automatically imported. I don't know why it was made that way, because there isn't anything else besides the converter module

Comment: my question is when we import the higher level module, don't we already import the lower ones?!

Comment: In short no. So you don't have to initialize unnecessary Code which would adding just more overhead